# Error deploying Play Framework on AWS Beanstalk Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, docker, playframework-2.3

Im running a Play Framework app on AWS Beanstalk with Docker (64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.1 running Docker 1.6.0).

Docker File:

```
FROM relateiq/oracle-java8
MAINTAINER XXXX
EXPOSE 9000
ADD files /
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "bin/app"]
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/app"]
CMD []
```

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
   "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
   "Ports": [{
       "ContainerPort": "9000"
   }]
}
```

When the instance first starts I get about 1 minute where its deployed as normal, then after I browse a few pages the error shows:

```
502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.6.2
```

The  error in the ElasticBeanstalk logs is:

```
Play server process ID is 1 This application is already running (Or delete /opt/docker/RUNNING_PID file).
```

I also get in the `/var/log/docker-events.log`the following messages every 30 seconds:

```
2015-05-30T20:07:58.000000000Z d0425e47095e5e2637263a0fe9b49ed759f130f31c041368ea48ce3d99d1e947: (from aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) start
2015-05-30T20:08:15.000000000Z d0425e47095e5e2637263a0fe9b49ed759f130f31c041368ea48ce3d99d1e947: (from aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) die
2015-05-30T20:08:16.000000000Z d0425e47095e5e2637263a0fe9b49ed759f130f31c041368ea48ce3d99d1e947: (from aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) start
2015-05-30T20:08:31.000000000Z d0425e47095e5e2637263a0fe9b49ed759f130f31c041368ea48ce3d99d1e947: (from aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest) die
```

Can anyone see my issue? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to `build.sbt` should resolve the issue:

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq("-Dpidfile.path=/dev/null")
```